Error when trying to load en_core_web_sm from spaCy module. "Error(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
I am trying to install spacy. When I run
pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy

it works successfully but then when I then run
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
I get the following error:
raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/spa
cy-models/master/compatibility.json (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021F46A38DC0>, 'Connection 
to raw.githubusercontent.com timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))

I have also tried running this
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1/en_core_web_sm-3. 7.1.tar.gz --no-deps 
Resulting in the same error and when I try using a proxy I get the following error.
Error(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)'))': /explosion/sp
acy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1.tar.gz
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /explosion/s
pacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1.tar.gz (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_
VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))

Please help.
